# Change Minecraft save location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a PC dual booted with Linux and Windows and Minecraft is installed on both. Now sometimes I play Minecraft in Linux and sometimes in Windows. I want to know if I could change the location where worlds are saved to a hard drive that is shared by both operating systems, so that I can use the same world on both operating systems.

Comment: I'm guessing you need a shared drive like an external hard drive or usb thumbdrive. I don't know much about dual-booting but it may be also possible to allocated a shared sector on C:? Yet another option is save to the cloud somehow like ZIPing worlds and putting them in your google drive/dropbox. However, that is a bit slow and tedious so maybe not a good option.

Comment: I do have a NTFS drive that us shared by both.. I just need to know how I can change save location to that drive

Comment: Oh okay I didn't realize that. So do you have minecraft installed two times, once for linux once for windows? If so, the solution is simple. Copy/save your saves folder on the shared drive. Delete minecraft from both OS. Download it again but when it asks for install location put it on the shared drive. Then copy your saves folder back into minecraft folder. From now on, when you create worlds they will be on both linux and windows.

Comment: @AshwinGupta Minecraft Install directory is not a thing in Linux, and affects only the launcher and runtime on Windows. The game itself will always install into `%appdata%\.minecraft` on Windows or `~/.minecraft` on Linux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Minecraft launcher allows you to change the folder it places your saves in (among other things) via the profile settings.

1. Create a "Minecraft" folder on a shared drive. Make sure you have read/write access to this folder from both Windows and Linux.
2. Start the Minecraft Launcher and click on <kbd>Installations</kbd>
3. Hover over the profile you want to change, click on <kbd>...</kbd>, then <kbd>Edit</kbd>.
4. Enter the folder on your shared drive in the Box labeled "Game Directory". The game will now place `saves`, `resourcepacks`, `screenshots` and `crash-reports` (maybe some more folders) in this Directory.
5. Repeat on the other OS.

Comment: Thanks.. I tried and it works superbly.. Better than my method..

Comment: For those in 2020: Open the launcher, click the Minecraft tab on the left, then click the "installations" tab in the main pane. You should see something like "Latest release". Hover over it and you will see a gray button with 3 dots on the right. Click that and select "Edit". You can then specify the game directory and other properties

Comment: @pooshla Thanks for the heads-up. I have edited the answer to reflect the current launcher.

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder called saves somewhere in your shared drive. (eg. D:\Xyz\saves). Move your worlds(if you have any saved) to this folder.

Then in Windows, create a symlimk to the folder:

1. Open elevated cmd.
2. Navigate to .minecraft folder: 
   `cd %appdata%\.minecraft`
3. Delete the saves folder from here.
4. In cmd, type:
   `mklink /D saves <path to saves folder>`
   eg. If your saves folder is D:\Xyz\saves, type:
   `mklimk /D saves D:\Xyz\saves`

Now reboot to Linux. In Linux,

1. Go to the shared drive which has saves folder.
2. Right click on saves folder and make link.
3. Rename the link to saves.
4. Go to .minecraft folder in your home directory and delete the saves folder from there.
5. Move the saves link here.

Now both operating systems will share the saved worlds.

Note: Shared drive must be NTFS for mklink to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Go to your user account and find roaming. go into it. in there is .minecraft (unless you changed if u changed fine what you changed it to) then open it and there will be a file called "Saves". Copy that onto a hard drive. then when you go to Linux open that hard drive and drag the saves into your save location which is in your minecraft launcher than edit profile and near the top.