# How do I access the same 'world' in different OSX user accounts?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I access the same 'world' in different OSX user accounts?  I initially downloaded Minecraft 12.2.1 while logged into my admin account on my MacBook Pro.  My 8 year old son immediately started using it and invested a lot of time in creating his own elaborate world.  In order to manage his time, I now want him to use his 'kids' account that has the OSX parental controls activated.  (And yes, I have designated Minecraft as an authorized application for his account.)  However, when we launch Minecraft in his Kids user account, his world is not available.  Hell hath no fury like an 8-year old who's asked to scrap his Minecraft creations and start from scratch.  I'm sure there's a simple configuration adjustment to make but I can't figure out what it would be.  Please help?

Answer (score 1):

You could try retrieving the folder which houses the world files generated upon creating it.

Open up "spotlight" and type `Library/Application Support/minecraft`. A finder window should show up. Navigate into the "saves" folder and you should see your world in there (folder names are world names)

From there, copy the world folder (cmd + c) then, in the finder window, press the menu option "Go" then "Go to folder". In the text box, type `/Users/` and click "Go".

You should see a folder in the finder window called "Shared". Paste the minecraft world folder into that folder, log in to your other account, go to the "Shared" folder and copy the world file again, then paste it back into the "Saves" folder which was in the first step. (Spotlight, library/appplication support/....")

You *should* be able to access that world on both accounts now. Have fun if it did work.

EDIT: To accommodate for a comment, a real neat trick would be to just have minecraft files in the shared folder. The only source I looked at for this was another question here: [Change Minecraft save location?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/255381/change-minecraft-save-location)

This basically says, there's an option in the launcher (before you start the game up) which says you can change the directory of the games files to another location. (i.e in the shared folder) so the world will be updated for both accounts. Only if you're going to be playing minecraft on both accounts I guess! worth a shot

Comment: Notice that you are now playing on a copy of the world, rather than on the original one. This means that whatever the child does on his own user account will not be visible on the admin account. In order to actually share a world, the world should be placed in a shared location and the launcher should be configured to use this folder instead of the default. I don't have experience with MacOS though, so I could be wrong

Comment: I wasn't sure if you could do that. If you could then that would be 10x better!